# If Cell is Blank then look at next sheet and copy

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with names and they are split over several sheets(teams). I want to build a second work book that has just the list of names on one sheet. Due to the fact the people change team all the time I can't use cut and paste.

So for I have in Sheet1 A2 =IF(ISBLANK('Team 1'!$A12),'Team 2'!$A12,'Team 1'!$A12)
The issue I have is when I get to the end of Team 1 (A47) it wants to bring back whats in Team 2 A47 not starting again in team 2 A12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of your people are listed starting on A12, write on your new sheet cell A2 and pull down:

```
=IF(ROW(team1!A12)<=(11+COUNTA(team1!A:A)),team1!A12,INDEX(team2!A:A,11+ROW('new-sheet'!A2)-COUNTA(team1!A:A)-1))
```

Comment: Thats great stuff thank you just working out how it works so I can add in team 3 now :)

Comment: in this case i think you will need a vba solution, i will work on an answer and edit my comment (please wait a little bit) - EDIT: try below

Comment: oh no no no, you dont need vba, you just need to change the counta for countif, change *both* COUNTA(team1!A:A) for COUNTIF(team1!A:A,">a")

Comment: Thank you that is great now I am pulling it apart to work out how to move on to team 3 but it is doing what I need it to do Thank you

Comment: Um not sure whay but it is only taking the first 10 from sheet 1 now......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176148/discussion-between-justin-greenwood-and-daniel-souza).

Comment: Thanks for the help on this I might look at exspanding to the full tables so not just A:A but A:NR if I can work it out.